# Can you have the iOS 6 3D button in an MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I'm developing an app that has mapping capabilities, and the 3D stuff in the native iOS 6 maps app really interested our CEO.

I was wondering if it's possible to have that button while inside a MKMapView or is still only available in the built-in maps app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [dev forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/689466) where an Apple staffer confirms that the MKMapView is different from the Maps app in iOS6

Comment: I have this same question.  Just to clarify, while the linked thread helps clarify the difference between MKMapView and MKMapItem, Apple does not say anything about whether these MKMapView is different in the two apps.  The user in question (on the other forum) is just learning the basic difference between "views" and "apps", it seems.

Comment: @Lucien - the thread title does say iOS6, but I've amended the reply to clarify which SDK it applies to